# How can I create a "media only" channel on Discord using a bot? (JS)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to code my Discord Bot (Js) in order to delete every type of text message in a specific channel while keeping images and videos. Anyone has any idea how can I do it?

Comment: what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property [`attachments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) of [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message). It returns a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of [`MessageAttachment`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment)s, which you can use to determine if there are attachments in the message. (links do not count as an attachment)

---

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    // Checking if the author is a bot.
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    // Deleting the message if there are 0 attachments in the message.
    if (message.attachments.size == 0) message.delete()
});
```